# Tiling of dodecahedra in quasicrystals.

Tags: geometry

I have a point with 5 line segments extending from it at equal lengths (L) and equal angles [2*arctan(ϕ)?] to each other. At the end of each line segment lies another point, with 4 additional line segments branching off of it with equal lengths and equal angles. This pattern repeats infinitely, until a line segment places a point at a distance < L to  another point.

I can see that a few repetitions of this pattern produces firstly pentagons, then later regular dodecahedron shapes, just by drawing this out in 3-dimensional software.

Without a deep understanding of the topic, I am under the impression that this system would eventually form a framework analogous to quasicrystals with dodecahedral rotational symmetry. This intuition comes from looking at images of these crystals.

I have no idea how to prove this. I'm a chemist by trade and my geometry background is not particularly strong. I am sure that there are proofs out there for this, but I have great difficulty in understanding them.

Comment: I don't understand how those 5 segments are placed: it isn't possible that all angles between any couple of them be the same.